# Sorting an array/File I/o

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have been working on an assignment to take a sentence from a file and output the number of character occurrences in the file and sort it from highest to lowest. The sentence in the file is "Oliver was a Golden Retreiver whose fur was long and golden.". The period in the file serves as a sentinel value. I am a little lost as to where to put the Sort function. The program compiles though it only shows a blank screen. Could anyone give me some tips on how to go about debugging these problems?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void swap_values(int& v1, int& v2);
int index_of_smallest(int list[],int start_index, int number_used);
void initialize(int list[]);
void Sort(int list[],int&number_used);
void characterCount(char ch, int list[]);
void readText(ifstream& intext, char& ch, int list[]);
void totalCount(int list[]);

int main()
{
    int letterCount[26], number_used;
    char ch;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("Data_Chapter_7_8.txt");

    if (!inFile)
    {
       cout << " Cannot open file." <<endl;
    }
    initialize(letterCount);

    while (inFile.get(ch))
    {
        readText(inFile,ch,letterCount);
    }

    totalCount(letterCount);

    inFile.close();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void initialize(int list[])
{
    for(int x = 0;x<26;x++)
    list[x] = 0;
}

void characterCount (char ch, int list[])
{
    ch = tolower(ch);
    if(static_cast<int>(ch)>=97&&(static_cast<int>(ch)<=122))
    list[static_cast<int>(ch)-97]++;
}

void readText(ifstream& intext, char& ch, int list[])
{ 
    if (ch != '.')
    {
        characterCount (ch,list);
    }
}

void totalCount(int letterCount[])
{
    for(int x=0;x<26;x++)
        if(letterCount[x]>0)
            cout<<static_cast<char>(x+97)<<" "<<letterCount[x]<<endl;
}

void Sort(int list[], int number_used)
{
    int index_of_next_smallest;
    int index;
    for(index= 0; index<number_used -1; index++)
        index_of_next_smallest = index_of_smallest(list, index,number_used);
    swap_values(list[index],list[index_of_next_smallest]);
}

int index_of_smallest(int list[], int start_index, int number_used)
{
    int index_of_min;
    int min = list[start_index];
    index_of_min = start_index;
    for (int index= start_index + 1; index < number_used; index++)
        if (list[index]>min)
        {
            min = list[index];
            index_of_min = index;
        }
    return index_of_min;
}

void swap_values(int& v1, int& v2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = v1;
    v1 = v2;
    v2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: the usual debugging technics are: (1) add print statements with values which will help to follow up the flow of the program (2) use debugger :).

Comment: try to narrow down you code and show the part of the program you really need help on.

Comment: I ran your program, I didn't get a blank screen, I got letters and counts which looked correct to me.

Comment: I want my program to sort the numbers that are displayed from highest to lowest

Comment: I just need help in the int main() part of the program because I don't really understand where to call my Sort function to.

Comment: The big problem with your code is that even if your sort function works (I didn't check) when you sort the counts you lose the information about which count relates to which letter. This is because you have chosen to use the *position* in the array to indicate which letter the count applies to. So I think you have chosen the wrong approach. Instead you should declare an array of structs, `struct LetterCount { char letter; int count; }; LetterCount letterCount[26];` You can sort this array without losing the information about which count applies to which letter.

Comment: It's probably a bit much to hear just when you think you've nearly finished that actually you were doing it wrong all along. But don't worry, all you need to do is replace your int array with a struct array like I showed you above. Most of the code is working now and will still work once you've fixed it to use a struct array.

Comment: It is unlikely to be your problem but not that `tolower()` expects a positive number. When using, e.g., my name on systems with a signed `char` it would crash your program because the `ü` creates a value outside the positive range of values. To use `tolower()` properly you need to cast its value to `unsigned char`, i.e., something like this: `tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch))`

Comment: You put your sort function after inFile.close();